# Bottom Sheet Initial Collapse not working

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, bottom-sheet

I need to show the text "Peek" at the collapsed state, but it shows the whole height.

How to hide the blank area above "Peek"?

It must show the "Peek" area at the first, then show "Content" after expand.

[image: Screenshot]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
        app:behavior_hideable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_bottom_dialog"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="80dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="Peek" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="Content" />

    </LinearLayout>



</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Do you access `BottomSheetBehavior` in your code and changing state or something else? i didn't mange to reproduce based on your `XML`

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply `bottom_sheet_behavior` to root view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottomSheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    app:behavior_hideable="false"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="80dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#121212">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/peekView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Peek"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contentView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Content"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

    </FrameLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

You can change the alpha properties of both content and peek views by `slideOffset` in `BottomSheetCallback`

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var bottomSheetBehavior: BottomSheetBehavior<ConstraintLayout>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        
        bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet)

        contentView.alpha = 0f
        peekView.alpha = 1f

        bottomSheetBehavior.addBottomSheetCallback(object :
            BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            
            override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {

                contentView.alpha = slideOffset
                peekView.alpha = 1 - slideOffset
            }

            override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {

            }
        })
    }
}
```

**Result**

[image: BottomSheet Peek and Content]